# How to get width and height of ContentChild TemplateRef in Angular 11

Tags: angular

I'm doing a web application with Angular 11. I need to show a list of cards, where each card has its own design.

I have created a component that receives a list of items and a child component to be projected, this child is another component that has the style (UI) I want to show.

**Component:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.scss']
})
export class ListComponent {

  @Input() items: any[];
  @ContentChild(TemplateRef) template: TemplateRef<any>;

  constructor() {
  }

}
```

**Template:**

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6" *ngFor="let i of items">

    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template; context: {$implicit: i}"></ng-container>

  </div>

</div>
```

**How do I use this component?** Here is an example.

```
<app-list [items]="myArray">
  <ng-template let-item>
    <!-- Here the component that we want to show -->
    <app-card-style-one [item]="item"></app-card-style-one>
  </ng-template>
</app-list>
```

All good so far. Now, I need to get the child's **width** and **height**.

I have tried this on my ListComponent:

```
  @Input() items: any[];
  @ContentChild(TemplateRef, {read: ElementRef}) template: TemplateRef<any>;

  constructor(
    private element: ElementRef
  ) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.element.nativeElement);
    console.log(this.template.elementRef.nativeElement);
    console.log(this.template.elementRef.nativeElement.nextSibling);
  }
```

No luck, I receives undefined or templateRef.createEmbeddedView is not a function.

My goal is to get the **width** and **height** of the child that is being projected. I will use those two variables to adjust other UI components that I have in my ListComponent.

Comment: It’s an interesting approach.. but why use a temple instead of an ng-content?

Comment: @MikeOne Using ng-content in my ListComponent I couldn't find a way to pass the item (object) to the component that will be projected. My approach was: I will tell you which component to render, but give me the item (obj) I need to show the information (UI). This is because ListComponent is using ngFor and only there is the item (object) available. My current experience doesn't help to go further than this.

Comment: The projected component in ng-content has access to the scope of the outer so you can pass in whatever you need using @Input()

Comment: Have you tried @ViewChild() decorator?

Comment: You can pass #mainScreen on child selector and
@ViewChild('mainScreen') elementView: ElementRef; in the component.
and then
let viewHeight = this.elementView.nativeElement.offsetHeight;

Comment: @MikeOne With ng-content I cannot access dynamic components, neither pass inputs because ng-content is not a component. If I use ng-content I need to project the card as is, no inputs and remember I need an object as a parameter, that is why I choose ng-template.

Comment: @AbhishekChokra I get the error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nativeElement')`. Could you provide an example? If I need to change the way of passing the child component, I will do it.

Comment: @AbhishekChokra Also, if I remember correctly, ContentChild is the only decorator to access the first child being projected, ViewChild cannot.